# third conditional with past simple?

Tags: tenses

In the third conditional it is correct to say "I would have attended if
 I had known he was giving a lecture." (past progressive)  Why can't I say  "I would have attended if I had know he gave a lecture." (past simple)?

Comment: "I had know" is always wrong.  It's "I knew" or "I had known". http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/know

Comment: Adding to what @Ste said, (if "had know" is a typo) you should understand "he was giving a lecture" as "he was going to give a lecture". There is difference in meaning between "he was giving a lecture" and "he gave a lecture".

Answer (score 2):

"… If I had known he gave a lecture" seems wrong to me. I can't imagine a situation where that would be correct.

The following, however, are correct:
A. "if I had known he was giving a lecture"
B. "if I had known he would give a lecture"
C. "if I had known he would be giving a lecture"
D. "if I had known he was going to give a lecture"
E. "if I had known he was going to be giving a lecture"

All of these mean basically the same thing - I didn't go because I didn't know there would be a lecture. The difference is only in emphasis. A. is neutral, whereas in B., C., D. and E. the speaker underscores that the decision not to go happened at a point before the event began (hence, the "future in the past" signalled by would/was going to).

Another possibility is:
F. "I would have attended if I had known he had given a lecture"
Here the speaker seems to be telling a story about something that happened in the past (possibly years earlier); the regret over missing the lecture is also in the past - unlike examples A.-F., where the implication is that the regret is still felt in the present. With F., the next sentence might be: "But I only found out about the lecture two weeks later."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use simple past because, in deep meaning, your sentence means "do something while something else is happening"...

Example:
"When I entered my house, my cat was running around wildly". (one event happens during a longer event.)

In your sentence the basic idea is "if I know about it, I go to whatever he is doing". (a punctual event (know) during a longer event (his lecture)).

It doesn't  matter if it's in present, second conditional or third, as the sentence uses the idea of "something happening inside a longer action" it requires the progressive to make sense :D

Hope that helps :D ask if you need clarification :D

UPDATE:

Some theory: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html

> Use the Past Continuous to indicate that a longer action in the past
>   was interrupted. The interruption is usually a shorter action in the
>   Simple Past. Remember this can be a real interruption or **just an
>   interruption in time.**

I think the "knowing" part of your statement is the interruption in time here mentioned.